# Create hotspot on Windows computer using specified encryption

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, hotspot

I have tried using netsh and third-party apps to create WiFi hotspots using my Windows 10 laptop, but they are all secured using WPA2 encryption.

I need to generate a hotspot that uses any other (or no) form of encryption. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Going to guess you're being downvoted for either your original question including factually incorrect information (that Chromecast doesn't support WPA2), for editing your question as substantially as you did, or for the fact that you're now asking a question about how to lower security without any reason. Can't say for sure, though, I only voted on your comment, not on the question.

Answer (score -1):

Not using the "hostednetwork" feature of Windows (which is what the third-party apps generally use). This feature always requires using WPA2.

However, Chromecast definitely supports WPA2 Personal (which is what hostednetwork uses). Is yours very out of date or something (though I'd have expected it to be supported from the start; it's certainly been supported for the last 18 months)? It doesn't currently support WPA2 Enterprise, but it definitely supports WPA2 PSK (Personal). See https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/3JpSNEtiFKw and https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3046409?hl=en

EDIT: Leaving my answer as it is, but the question was originally about Chromecast, thus my answer specifically addressing it. If there's anything unhelpful or incomplete about the answer, please leave a comment so I can improve it.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=326

Comment: Good to know, thanks @JoelChristophel. That shouldn't matter at all here, though, because the hostednetwork feature uses WPA2-PSK, not Enterprise.

Comment: My question is less about the chromecast (removed from question) and more about using other forms of security. How would I do this other than using hostednetwork?

Comment: To address your edit, I'd say your answer is incomplete in that it does not specify what to use, but rather what not to use.

Comment: @JoelChristophel: Good point. I don't believe there *is* a solution built into Windows, but there's probably a third-party WiFi driver configuration utility that does it. It certainly used to be possible, in the days before Windows included WiFi support directly, and it can be done in Linux, but I don't know of a tool (or driver) to do this in Windows without external hardware.